# Incorrect resonator/crystal PCB layout?

Tags: pcb, schematics, crystal, resonator

Hobbyist developing first PCB. Only caught this on my PCB/Schematic design after I had received them, was too focused on functionality of other components.

Resonator designed like crystal, resonator GND pins not going to GND. How it's designed.

[image]

How it should be designed according to datasheet.

[image]

Edit: Ignore schematic title, its obviously a resonator.
Edit+: https://datasheet.lcsc.com/szlcsc/1811141821_Yangxing-Tech-X322516MLB4SI_C13738.pdf - Apologies, thought resonators all wired the same.
[image]
**Have I ruined my PCB? **

Thanks :)

Comment: How many did you order? 1? 10 000? If the former, jump wire.

Comment: Please link to exact resonator part number and datasheet. Without datasheet we can't know what is the right way to connect it.

Comment: Cheers for the comment, only 10 but lead time is around 2 weeks incl. shipping but no one to blame but myself. Was just wondering if it would work before thinking of alternatives, may be able to solder bridge one to GND copper layer and jump the other, Thanks! :) Added link to datasheet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well the two GND pins are probably there to bring casing and everything to a defined potential; thus, performance will be better when you connect them, but it might work without. Hard to tell.

However, this connection (for the low frequency of 16 MHz) doesn't need to be crazy good – a short, well-soldered wire that connects the two ground pins to the nearest ground contact should work.

Generally, unless you're doing really high-frequency things, or more than 2 layers, if in doubt, have a ground plane. If you have one, finding a place where to solder these might be really easy (you can even scratch off a bit of solder mask, apply flux and solder directly onto that.)

Comment: Beautiful, exactly what I was after and +1 adding some information, I love learning how things work in what applications. I do have a ground plane but only one ground can be soldered to it, other will be jumped as suggested in comments above. Now that I know there's a slim chance it may work, I will try a board as is and update this post in the RARE chance anyone does it similar. Thanks!

Comment: Update: Without GND resonator did not function, was however able to connect the GND's to ground plane relatively easily. Thanks.